# Translating Web Pages (Plain HTML) in-line

Tags: html, translation, html-editor

#### Purpose

So I have a web page I want to translate. It's just HTML for the most part, but it's in a language the people I want to read it can't understand. I tried using the dev tools in Chrome to just edit the HTML in line, but that doesn't work (it saves the original HTML despite of whatever changes you've made).

#### Requirements

- Mac OSX compatible
- Simple interface
- Allows in-line editing of HTML
- Preferably allows me to totally ignore HTML tags themselves
- Allows me to save the resulting translated page to file

Comment: Am still not clear with your question, do you mean translate = editing the DOM? if yes, than edit via console and save the page, that should suffice, or checkout OneNote clipper.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did the 'edit the DOM in Chrome console and save' and it saved the non-edited version. This is the source of the question.

Comment: I used chrome console to tweak the text, and saved the page, works for me...